# Error in getting this piece of C run in dev c++ - "Syntax error before * token"

Tags: c, pointers, syntax-error, dev-c++

EDIT: The program includes the header  and  which are incompatible with gcc and win7. I think I have to use dosbox with turbo c to run the program...

The whole programme is here: http://blackwhite.8866.org/bhh/asc.c

Below are the related code that gets the error message:

```
main(){
    char far *p = (char far *),0xA0000000,far *py, far *px;
    /* some other codes */
}
```

I have no idea why there would be this error since the code is given by the professor as a homework (we have to create the same programme in 8086 assembly).

I guess the problem is with Dev c++ but I have no idea about it either...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `char far, *p, ...;`?

Comment: Sorry, typo! Changed now :)

Comment: Remove comma from `(char far *),0xA0000000`. Also I think that you shall remove `far` from `far *py` and  `far *px`.

Comment: Just tried but this doesn't work. The error becomes "syntax error before "far" :(

Comment: Then, remove `far` from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
   char far *p = (void far *)0xA0000000;  // Initialize a far * to point to address.
   void far *py;                          // type of far pointer required. (void, char, int, etc.)
   void far *px;                          // type of far pointer required. (void, char, int, etc.
   /* some other codes */

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: @alk, lazyness on my part. A void pointer type can be used to initialize any other pointer type.  And it is a way of saying "I don't really know what resides at address 0xA0000000.

Comment: @Mahonri MoriancumerThat doesn't work.... I found that the code includes headers that doesn't compatible with gcc. I wonder if this can be the problem too?

Comment: @Sue, if you add this line, (perhaps up by your '#include' lines): "#define far"  It should fix things.  The 'far' keyword is not part of the C standard; but several compilers introduced it (mostly in support of 16-bit DOS applications).  The idea was to help the compiler know if it should implement a 16-bit pointer (near) or a 32-bit pointer (far).  You will probably find that your gcc environment uses 32-bit pointers (far) by default.  Hence, just define 'far' to 'do nothing' and you won't have to go through the code and remove the 'far' keyword from everywhere.